# The benefits of Java 64x (bit) version in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering what the benefits are for Java 64x version, Does it help the game run smoother, Faster, Enhance graphics?

Comment: Questions that deal with a certain game shouldn't include the dock it runs on. Based on whether or not it "runs smoother" is off-topic because it is opinion based. Some people might say that Their computer runs better than others when it actually doesn't.

Comment: This is more about Java than it is Minecraft.  Minecraft gets a boost from 64-bit Java, but so would anything running on Java, not just Minecraft.  I don't think this is within our purview.

Comment: @dlras2 If a question can be answered with just knowledge of Java, without game-specific domain knowledge, then it's not really a good fit for this site.

Comment: @Young Guilo I tagged this as java as well...

Comment: Yep, asking "why Minecraft recommends Java 64 for Far render distance" is not about Minecraft as a game, it is about Minecraft as a program --> gamedev.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is does not require gaming expertise.

Comment: @OrcJMR It's not about Minecraft at all.  It's about Java.  If it's acceptable anywhere (and I don't know that for sure; double-check their help center, just in case), I'd say SuperUser.

Comment: Should I have tagged this as something else? I tagged it with minecraft because "Minecrafters" might know, I tagged java as well because Java people may know.

Comment: @fbueckert "Why *Minecraft* recommends Java 64" is not about Java in general, you could as well say 64-bit processors in general. A program can benefit from increased register size in many ways. On the other hand, SuperUsers can give an educated guess, indeed.

Comment: @Bananaman Tags are a second concern, actually. What's more important, this is the wrong *site* for this question. Here on Arqade we discuss playing games, not programming them :)

Comment: @OrcJMR Ah, Where could I go?

Comment: I have searched google...

Comment: @OrcJMR This isn't about programming Minecraft - this is a specific question about playing the game - in either 32- or 64-bit mode.

Comment: That'd be either http://superuser.com/ for general computer knowledge ("why is 64 bits cooler than 32 bits?") or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for game development ("why could minecraft recommend 64 bits for Far render distance").

Comment: @dlras2 For that, answer is "64 bits for Far, no difference otherwise". But if you look very closely, the last word is "why?" - which is not about playing.

Comment: @OrcJMR But the *rest* of the questions ("smoother, Faster, Enhance graphics?") **are** about playing, and on topic if answerable objectively, which I believe they are. "Why?" might not be, but isn't the main question - just human nature to be curious.

Comment: I support this question, because we do allow technical questions about games such as framerate enhancements and other stuff. It is about running the game and if you cannot run it properly, you cannot play it in the first place. Also, we do deal with Servers and other stuff so I see absolutely no reason to disallow this content. Otherwise we need to cease all technical questions about games and servers.

Comment: These comments are getting slightly out of control.  Please take it to Meta.

Comment: @dlras2 Exactly!

Comment: @Raven Dreamer That's is for server, Not for client

Comment: For the record, this appears to be on topic and already answered by another question.

Comment: @Bananaman Doesn't matter in this case; Java is java. (And the client *is* the server in single player)